# How to construct an array consisting of all paths of a given length in discretised 2D-space

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop

Starting at (0,0) in the plane, given a positive integer n, I want to generate all paths consisting of n-1 steps away from (0,0). A step can be either one step to the right or one step up. For example, if n=4, then a path would be (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2). I'm currently using python

I've tried letting some parameter count the number of steps I'm taking and then using a while loop to restrict the number of steps, and for looping through my starting array [[[0,0]]].

```
def f(n):
    A=[[[0,0]]]
    s=0
    while (int(s+1)<int(n)):
        for i in A:
            i.append([i[-1][0]+1,i[-1][1]])
            A.append(i+[i[-1][0],i[-1][1]+1])
        s+=1
    return A

print f(2)
```

I'm getting an error 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**' on line 8. I also have a feeling that there are various other problems with the above code but am not too sure the best way to go about this

Comment: Can you explain why you expect `(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2)` for `n=4` ?

Comment: You're trying to do something along the lines of `[1,2,3,4][2][1]`.

Comment: @Austin this is just one example. Another would be (0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0). Both consist of paths of length 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. This problem is ideally suited to recursive techniques.
If you have a path of length N at point P = (x, y) then you know it forms two
possible paths of length N+1, one to point (x+1, y) and one to point (x, y+1).

The only other thing you know is that there is one path of length zero at the starting point. Given that, you can compute the paths of length 1, the paths of length 2, and
so on. To separate the logic of path generation from the business of consuming the
paths I'd suggest using a generator function, allowing your logic to `yield` a
new path whenever is finds one. You can then iterate over this generator
to enumerate the paths. This appears to work:

```
def paths(in_path, N=1):
    if N==1:
        yield in_path
    else:
        x, y = in_path[-1]
        yield from paths(in_path+[(x+1, y)], N-1)
        yield from paths(in_path+[(x, y+1)], N-1)

for path in paths([(0, 0)], 4):
    print(path)
```

The output I see is

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]
```

which, gratifyingly, appears to include the example you gave.

Comment: Sorry, I keep trying to use MathJax notation in SO - that's what the dollar sign stuff is about.